# Freshly clicked

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, marketing

In the UK, Tesco (a supermarket) has an advertising campaign where fruits or vegetables appear next to the phrase "freshly clicked". For example:

[image]

On the one hand, we could not think much about it and take it as a simple association of fruits and vegetables with freshness and care, perhaps evoking a kind of "home made". A pure rhetorical marketing campaign.

On the other hand, **the phrase seems to me to be formally incorrect**. Clicked seems to be used as a verb of [click](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/click), perhaps related to its computer equivalent of "selecting something". The adjective "freshly" is indicating a characteristic of the clicking process. But what is to select something *in a fresh fasion*? For example, *softly clicked* or *carefully clicked* makes sense, because the adjectives do indicate a characteristic of the clicking process (soft and careful, respectively). But freshly?

Is this phrase pure marketing yet grammatically incorrect? Or is there a sense in which the phrase is well-defined? Maybe an idiom?

Comment: It might be playing off the phrase *freshly picked*.

Comment: Advertising catch-phrases don't need to follow normal rules; they just need to catch the eye (obviously, yours has been caught) and increase sales. Like much of the 'English' one has to endure in song lyrics, this does not fit ELU's requirements for standard usages.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: It's a jokey reference to ordering groceries online. As Lawrence says, a pun on 'freshly picked'.

Comment: I don't understand the question. _Clicked_ is quite clearly a form of the verb _click_, the past participle; _freshly_ is an adverb that describes it. _Freshly_ means ‘newly, recently’. There is no “indicating a characteristic of the clicking progress” involved. What is the actual problem here? Quite apart from the fact that grammaticality doesn’t really enter into it at all, why would it be incorrect in any way?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I think your not understanding there can be confusion is part of the reason why the slogan is effective ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'*Fresh*' is a powerful selling descriptor.  Who wants anything that is '*stale*' or '*out-of-date*'?

['Freshly picked'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=freshly+picked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfreshly%20picked%3B%2Cc0) has been a stock phrase for some time.  Used widely by greengrocers it serves a double function.

> '*Fresh*' fruit and vegetables are *not stale*; (i.e. fresh meaning  condition);
>
> *Freshly* picked fruit and vegetables were *very recently* growing in the field/orchard (i.e. fresh meaning very recently).

Type "*Freshly picked*" into Google today and you will see that it is a standard marketing phrase for almost anything, including things that have never been growing organically.  In this inorganic context 'freshly' is used to suggest that an item is 'of its time', part of the zeitgeist (i.e. it has the latest technology and style).

*Freshly **clicked*** plays on this familiar marketing phrase.  It is an updated version of the longstanding '*freshly picked*' for a digital age.  The idea is that Tesco stores/delivery vehicles contain (only) groceries, and other merchandise, that are 'fresh' (recently growing/of their time) 'clicked' (selected/picked from an online list).

Comment: Don't forget that *picking* is also the term for selecting something from stock, by referring to a *picking list* listing what is required. But yes, it's a play on words *picked* -> *clicked*.

Comment: In other words with a simple (mouse) "click" consumers can "pick" their produce and have it transported to their homes.

Comment: I too understand this as promoting a website, not a van.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - yes, of course, the slogan promotes the Tesco brand.  As it happens, I've only seen the slogan on the sides of their delivery vehicles and it certainly works the slogan well to suggest that, as one of their delivery vehicle speeds by, you are seeing 'in action' just how seriously Tesco takes it job to provide items that have been freshly picked ;-)

Comment: I think it promotes a service where you can order your produce by clicking on it on Tesco's website. Then a van delivers it to you while it's still fresh. Freshly picked (by the grower) and freshly clicked (by you).